# Как сгенерить селектор и кликнуть на данный элемент WebdriverIO + Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пишу тесты для веб-портала.
Есть код:

```js
var transactionId;
client
.getAttribute("p.tac", "transaction-id").then(function(attr){
          transactionId = attr;
        })
.click('a[href=#admin/' + transactionId + ']')//Это не работает!!!
```

Надо, чтобы *href* для ссылки генерировался, исходя из приходящего *ID*, беру его из атрибута `<p>` элемента.

**Обновление**

Элемент с данным `href` есть на странице! Проблема в том что `WebdriverIO` не хочет принимать этот селектор как строку, хотя `typeof` возвращает `string`.

Comment: А у вас есть элемент с такой ссылкой, по которой вы решили кликнуть?

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая проблема была при запросах вида

```
.click('input[name=images[]]')
```

Нужно было экранировать квадратные скобки:

```
.click('input[name=images\\[\\]]')
```

Возможно решетка # парсится как селектор по id.